# How do I tell TortoiseSVN to not make itself available on WebDav Resources not under it's control?

Tags: svn, sharepoint, tortoisesvn, sharepoint-2013, ignore

Firstly apologies if this is a really dumb question, it's been a bit of a crash course for me recently.

We run a SharePoint 2013 farm which hosts approx. 2,000,000 files and recently changed to a FQDN structure from a partially qualified domain.

Some of our users use TortoiseSVN to version control documents outside of SharePoint, and have been doing so for a number of years without a problem.

Since the FQDN change however, TortoiseSVN has been making itself available on the right click Context Menu when browsing SharePoint via Windows Explorer (WebDav) and, as the user doesn't have permissions to access .svn files within the Site Collection, it's generating 1000's of 401 requests which mean that right clicking on any SharePoint location through windows explorer now takes approx. 3 minutes to bring up the context menu.

I can't seem to find a way to tell TortoiseSVN to not make itself available on FQDN SharePoint Locations. For now the end users have uninstalled it and confirmed the issue is resolved however they would really like to continue using it if possible.

I know you can use svn:ignore to ignore Paths within a SVN Project however is there a way to tell TortoiseSVN to not make itself available on FQDN SharePoint Locations?

Answer (score 1):

```
Settings dialog->General->Context Menu
```

Textbox labelled "`Do not show the context menu for the following paths:`" should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Stefan - Thanks for the response however I have tried that and it is still showing the context menu. I entered it in the following format: \\<fqdn path>\*.. would that be correct?

Comment: @AdeStokes adding `\\MyShare\MyData\*` (note the wildcard) works perfectly for me.

Comment: @bahrep I tried \\myshare.company.com\sites\\* however it's still showing TortoiseSVN in the context menu unfortunately.

Comment: @Stefan I did as suggested and I have managed to hide the context menu however according to Fiddler, TortoiseSVN is still making calls to .svn files stored in the WebDav location

Comment: @AdeStokes you also have to exclude those paths under Settings->IconOverlays to make sure the status for those files is not fetched. And "Show excluded folders as normal" must be unchecked, otherwise it tries to check whether a folder is a working copy root.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks! Worked like a charm. Looking back I think I had tried both settings individually but not together which would explain it. Thanks again for the assistance.